# How can I enter information in a search bar using the requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from this website: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi

I have a list of scientific species names that I want to enter in the search bar one by one, and then extract relevant information from the page using a HTML parser. I can't seem to figure out how to enter a string in the search bar. Is this possible using the requests module or should I use another module for this? The HTML line of the search bar looks like this:

```
<input id="searchtxt" type="text" name="name" value="" size"">
```

If I search the webpage manually, then the line looks like this:

```
<input id="searchtxt" type="text" name="name" value="Hyperia galba" size"">
```

Strangely the URL doesn't change after the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this url: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?name=

You can search things without putting things in the search bar

Example:

```py
import requests

q = "Phage E"
url = f'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?name={q}'
info = requests.get(url)
print(info.text)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much! Did you figure this out just by trying, or how did you find out the solution?

Comment: @DogeButt I figured this out because most websites have a query that makes a different link for searching up different things for example: https://www.google.com/search?q=python